# Avoid using "for" on "foreach"

Tags: php

To avoid use for and foreach in the same time, i am looking for a good trick to manipulate foreach to get the result i want to.

I have this code:

```
foreach($array['database']['tables'][0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' - ' . $key ."\n";
}
```

I won't use `FOR` here: `$array['database']['tables'][ HERE ]`

Are there any trick to avoid using `FOR` on the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simple:

```
foreach ($array['database']['tables'] as $table) {

  foreach ($table as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' - ' . $key ."\n";
  }

}
```